# How can I export a model (Predictor) trained on Amazon Forecast?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-forecast

On Amazon Forecast, how can I export a model (a Predictor in Forecast lingo) that I already trained? For example, export an ARIMA or Prophet model weights to a file t be downloaded or stored on S3.

Running forecasts on new data is just too slow and I would like to use Forecast to train models and eventually deploy them somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: you can't export the models from Forecast

Ref: https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-forecast-samples/issues/104#issuecomment-763119541